# LNK errors GTest in vS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing, googletest

I am writting a simple Google Test class with no fixture.

- Is it mandatory to have a `setUp()` and a `tearDown()` for it ?
- I have LNK errors when building. Error explicits `unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void_thiscall testing::Test::SetUp(void)"` Where does this come from ?

LNK errors are LNK2019, LNK2001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the `gtest.lib` inside the properties for the project, in Properties > Linker > Input > Additionnal Dependencies

This solved it.